# To create a reference variable or not to when using Scanner class?

Tags: java, variables, input, reference

Normally, Scanner inputs are coded like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerWithReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a double value: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double newValue = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(newValue);
    }
}
```

However, you can also write them like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerWithoutReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a double value: ");

            double newValue = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble(); 

            System.out.println(newValue);
    }
}
```

Both programs print out the double value from the same input. I understand why this works. I also understand that creating a reference variable input allows me to use input.close() to prevent resource leaks.

However, I don't know when to do it the first way or the second way. I normally see it written the first way. Can I get some clarification on why some would write this code the second way?

Comment: I don't see a `newValue` variable in the first program at all. However, as far as your question goes, it doesn't matter.

Comment: My bad, I was formatting the code to display correctly and accidentally deleted it. I will fix it now.

Comment: @user93353 : It matters... Programming practices matter...

Answer (score 1):

I would always do it the first way. The possibility or crashing because the scanner does not read a double is in my opinion as likely to happen as it is actually going to get a double.

Practice defensive programming at all times.

```
java.util.Scanner;
java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class ScannerWithReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double newValue = 0.0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a double value: ");

        try {
            newValue = scanner.nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("Thanks for the double");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry not a dobule, try again");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've heard about it. I'm still learning programming on my own, and I haven't gone to that point. Thanks, I'll take your advice.

Comment: I would to add that I just learned exception handling (heard about it but now I know how to implement it). This is a response to your edit that included the exception handling. Thanks. This clarifies some things for me like the meaning of defensive programming.

Answer (score 0):

its better to use the second one because its much more optimized code.
if you are a good programmer you can try the second one that pretty good.
for a beginner its better to use the first one its more descriptive and can understand whats actually happening.